# Adding AVCaptureDeviceInput to CaptureSession resets/refocuses video

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiosession

A video recording app. I want it to work without stopping/pausing background music (when user listens to Apple Music for instance). This I can do nicely with setting category to `mixWithOthers` on `AVAudioSession` singleton.

After setting the category I also need to add `AVCaptureDeviceInput` to `AVCaptureSession` (so audio will get recorded). This results a glitch/hiccup to background audio and also video resets/refocuses.

I have investigated and it seems background audio glitch is something that can't be avoided, but video should not reset itself when input is added. The result of video resetting is that the first frame of the recorded video is either dark/black or it starts with out of focus frame and then focuses.

Also checked Snapchat ios app and they also have audio glitch when starting recording, but video starts to record smoothly. What am I doing wrong.

My code:

```
//Setting audio session to mixWithOthers upon startup
let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

do {
    try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord,
                            with: [.mixWithOthers])
    if session.mode != AVAudioSessionModeVideoRecording {
        try session.setMode(AVAudioSessionModeVideoRecording)
    }
} catch let error {
    print("avsession category error: \(error)")
}
```

And then:

```
//Just before recording starts will add audio input
let audioDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio)
do
{
    let deviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: audioDevice) as AVCaptureDeviceInput
    if captureSession.canAddInput(deviceInput) {
        captureSession.addInput(deviceInput)
    }
    else {
        print("Could not add audio device input to the session")
    }


}
catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
    return
}
```

Would it be possible to do this without any glitches at all?
If not then how could I make it at least like Snapchat (no video reset upon addInput call)?

Comment: Not sure if it's okay to share external files in SO, but I've uploaded a clean sample project of this to:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1x7bl4fkboxu9cf/VideoInputGlitch.zip?dl=0

Comment: AVCaptureDevice has property .focus probably set to autoFocus in your case, try setting it to locked.

Comment: CameraEngine.swift and VideoWriter.swift files are missing in the project.

Comment: Oh thanks for pointing this out. I uploaded another one with camera engine classes: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/whu2liv1nsse4u1/VideoInputGlitch050417.zip?dl=0
And thank you so much for taking a look.
I'll also try .autoFocus thing in a minute.

Comment: Are you calling beginConfiguration / commitConfiguration on the session before changing inputs ?

Comment: @TanelTeemusk , you should add all the inputs at a same time while adding video input as well.

Comment: @SarfarazKhan Yes, tried this. As soon as I star a session with AudioDevice, it'll do the glitch in music.

Comment: @Kamil.S Thanks for the tip. Now if I use focusMode = .locked on the device I get no focusing, but video still resets resulting a black frame in the beginning.
Another suggestion that I've been investigating without results so far is that I add the inputs all at once (audio and video) but set AVCaptureInputPort isEnabled = false for sound port. This too makes it glitch. Really puzzled here...

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed `AVCaptureSession addInput` resets silence set by `AVAudioSession AVAudioSessionCategory(Solo)Ambient` category

```
 Category                              Silenced   Interrupts
 AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient         Yes        No
 AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient     Yes        Yes
 AVAudioSessionCategoryMultiRoute      No         Yes
 AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord   No         Yes
 AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback        No         Yes
 AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord          No         Yes
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/AudioSessionCategoriesandModes/AudioSessionCategoriesandModes.html

> When the user moves the Silent switch (or Ring/Silent switch on iPhone) to the “silent” position, your audio is silenced.
>
> `AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient`—Playback only. Plays sounds that add polish or interest but are not essential to the app’s use. Using this category, your audio is silenced by the Ring/Silent switch and when the screen locks.
>
> `AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient`—(Default) Playback only. Silences audio when the user switches the Ring/Silent switch to the “silent” position and when the screen locks. This category differs from the `AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient` category only in that it interrupts other audio.

Answer (score -1):

So from your question, this sentence specifically:

> The result of video resetting is that the first frame of the recorded video is either dark/black or it starts with out of focus frame and then focuses.

Indicates to me you are adding the `audioInput` after having begun video recording. Is it possible to add the `audioInput` device before video begins recording? I imagine it's expected behavior for the video to "freeze" when adding another input source, since the `AVCaptureSession` essentially just takes inputs and outputs a file, more or less. I'd imagine that adding the `audioInput` device before recording would solve that issue in the final product, since that action would not end up in the recording! :)

Another comment that was mentioned was:

> Are you calling beginConfiguration / commitConfiguration on the session before changing inputs ?
>
> – SeanLintern88 Apr 10 at 15:30

I think this was not addressed by the question author, and could also be the cause of issues. As shown in [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356061/avcapturesession-record-video-with-audio), you need to add the `audioInput` device between a `begin/commit configuration` call.

In general, I find the core [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avcapturesession) very helpful, and will probably have more info for more things you'll likely want to do.